# Critical number of processes for monitoring?

Tags: process, nagios

I was going to setup my Nagios/Icinga to monitor the processes on my machines and in case of a high number warn or error me via email.

I know for monitoring load, you would use something like this:

`num of cpu * desired percent / 100`

The main question is:

Is there any formula such as: `num of cpu * XXX` to get a decent value of the allowed number of processes on a system?

Is this also linked to `ulimit` somehow?

Comment: Why should there be a critical number of processes for a system? There isn't. You want to monitor the resources they use, not their number.

Comment: @ClassStacker Is there no such thing as a critical number of processes on any system?

Comment: I thought I already said "no". It means "not per se", not in the sense of load, memory, HDD activity, or similar. There _is_ a kind of an (artificial) limit but it's unlikely that it is relevant for you. At that point, you need to specify what "critical" actually means -- in terms of what your system needs to do -- does it have to spawn thousands of new processes in a short time, and what happens if that doesn't succeed -- we can't know this. But _you_ know how to search the web, don't you?